# Alguna funcion que me permita enmascarar con xxxx al llenar datos de tarjeta de credito con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Existe alguna forma de poder enmascarar con xxxx y luego desemascarar con un boton, los campos de un input para tarjeta de credito.

Answer (score 2):

Para ellos puedes usar la propiedad `type="password"` de HTML para ocultar el contenido, y un botón con un evento  `onclick` para visualizar el contendido cambiado la propiedad a `type="text"`. Mira el siguiente ejemplo.

```js
function ver(element){
  let id = element.getAttribute('for')
  let el_input = document.getElementById(id)
  let estado = el_input.getAttribute("type")
  let nuevo_estado = estado === "text" ? "password" : "text"
  el_input.setAttribute("type", nuevo_estado)
}
```

```html
<label for="card"> Numero: </label>
<input type="password" id="card">
<label for="card" onclick="ver(this)">Ver</label>
<br/>
<label for="cv"> Digito Verificación: </label>
<input type="password" id="cv">
<label for="cv" onclick="ver(this)">Ver</label>
```

También recomiendo lee [validar tarjetas de crédito con javascript](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/credit-card-validation.php) para que mejores la seguridad y experiencia de usuario.